# How to convert array of object into nested array of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-table

I am having an array of objects like this

```
[
    {
        name: "dhanush",
        goals: ["goal 1","goal 2"],
        goalAmount: ["10000","20000"]
    },
    {
        name: "kumar",
        goals: ["goal 3", "goal 4"],
        goalAmount: ["30000","40000"]
    },
    {
        name: "test",
        goals: ["goal 5"],
        goalAmount: ["50000"],
    }
]
```

Is that possible to convert the above array of object into the below structure like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "dhanush",
    "goals": "---",
    "goalAmount":"---",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 1",
        "goalAmount":" 10000"
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 2",
        "goalAmount":" 20000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "kumar",
    "goals": "---",
    "goalAmount":"---",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 3",
        "goalAmount":" 30000"
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 4",
        "goalAmount":" 40000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "goals": "goal 5",
    "goalAmount":"50000"
  }
]
```

In the first data, you can see the user has multiple goals (which means the array length is more than 1), If the goal length is more than one, need to create another key and move the goal data into the above structure like this.

Why I am doing this because I got an ask to create a table that needs to support expandable rows. I used `@tanstack/react-table` for this row expansion. Here you can find the working demo link - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-1t77ks?file=/src/App.js

In the demo, you can see the row can expand. For the expansion that table requires the data format like this.

I tried to do something like this,

```
var data = [
    {
        name: "dhanush",
        goals: ["goal 1","goal 2"]
    },
    {
        name: "kumar",
        goals: ["goal 3", "goal 4"]
    },
    {
        name: "test",
        goals: ["goal 5"]
    }
]


let result = data.map((val,i) => {
  return {
    name: val.name,
    ...(val.goals.length === 1 && {goals: val.goals[0]}),
    [val.goals.length > 1 && 'subRows']: data.map((t,j) => {
      return{
       name: "",
       goals: val.goals[j]
      }
       
    }),
  }
})
```

But the output I am getting like this instead of the actual structure

```
[
  {
    "name": "dhanush",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 2"
      },
      {
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "kumar",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 3"
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 4"
      },
      {
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "goals": "goal 5",
    "false": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "goals": "goal 5"
      },
      {
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Could you please help to achieve this?

Comment: updated the expected data structure!  Is it possible to make it ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this all in a single object literal, it's a confusing way to create properties conditionally. Just write normal conditional statements.

To get the `goalAmount`, use the index argument to the `map()` callback function so you can get the corresponding element in another array.

```js
var data = [
    {
        name: "dhanush",
        goals: ["goal 1","goal 2"],
        goalAmount: ["10000","20000"]
    },
    {
        name: "kumar",
        goals: ["goal 3", "goal 4"],
        goalAmount: ["30000","40000"]
    },
    {
        name: "test",
        goals: ["goal 5"],
        goalAmount: ["50000"],
    }
]


var result = data.map(({
  name,
  goals,
  goalAmount
}) => {
  let item = {
    name
  };
  if (goals.length == 1) {
    item.goals = goals[0];
    item.goalAmount = goalAmount[0];
  } else {
    item.goals = "---";
    item.subRows = goals.map((g, i) => ({
      name: "",
      goals: g,
      goalAmount: goalAmount[i]
    }));
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to update another key also based on the same condition? I have updated the expected data structure result for your reference.

Please let me know the feasibility of it.

Comment: Of course it's possible, just index the `goalAmount` array the same as the `goals` array. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This here

```
[val.goals.length > 1 && 'subRows']: data.map((tm j) => {
```

evaluates to `false` if there's 1 goal or less, and results in the string property `false`. Then you're mapping the whole `data` again inside that for some reason. Only map over the goals of the current element you're iterating over, the `val.goals`.

Because the different possible resulting objects are pretty differently strucured, I think this would be easier to manage if they were entirely separate - return `{ name, goals: goals[0] }` if there's only one goal, and return a completely different object mapping over the `goals` otherwise.

```js
var data=[{name:"dhanush",goals:["goal 1","goal 2"],goalAmount:["10000","20000"]},{name:"kumar",goals:["goal 3","goal 4"],goalAmount:["30000","40000"]},{name:"test",goals:["goal 5"],goalAmount:["50000"]}];

const result = data.map(({ name, goals, goalAmount }) => {
  return goals.length === 1
    ? { name, goals: goals[0], goalAmount: goalAmount[0] }
    : {
        name,
        goals: '---',
        subRows: goals.map(
          (goal, i) => ({ name: '', goal, goalAmount: goalAmount[i] })
        )
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to update another key also based on the same condition? I have updated the expected data structure result for you reference.

Please let me know the feasibility of it.

Comment: Use the index while mapping to access the same indexed item in the other array in the object. Remember to include your full input and desired output when first posting a question.